# Light sensitive resistor

Tags: light

I have a CdSe light sensitive resistor which goes from 0.1k to 30k light->dark .

It works fine outside the circuit. When I pass +/- 1V 400Hz AC across it, it seems to always have a low resistance. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Would you post the schematic of the circuit?

Comment: Yup, how do you determine the resistance when it's in the circuit and has excitation?

Comment: I'm powering it from a headphone (at 400Hz) and reading through a microphone (from the same mobile phone).  The resistance gives the same microphone reading as when the LSR is changed to a known low resistance.

Comment: What do you mean "reading"? You're going to have to post the circuit for us to understand.

Comment: I'll try and explain - I havent a circuit diagram or a way of getting it to you...my android phone jack has 4 connections - left/right headphone, microphone and ground.  i plug a 4 pole 3.5 mm connector into the phone and at the other end i strip the wires and have 10k across right headphone/microphpone and 10k across microphone/ground.  I then play with putting different resistors in series or parallel (or the LSR) with the headphone/microphone 10k resistor.

Comment: I 'play' a single 400Hz note down the headphone and 'read' what comes back up the  microphone.  I draw a graph and can then get the resistance across headphone/microphone from the value 'read' at the microphone.   when i have a (10k and LSR in series) in parallel to the 10k across headphone and microphone, it behaves as if the resistnce of the LSR is not how it behaves when outside the circuit with a multimeter.

Comment: try varying the frequency and see if the LDR response changes

Comment: Instead of posting more information in comments, it might be more helpful to include the information in the original question. That way, the question is complete, and makes sense without people having to read through comments too.